# Duplicate the field in the first column

Tags: linux

I have the below input

```
L12194C;               
           ;1;8;12     
           ;2;30;46    
           ;3;49;71    
           ;4;0;0      
           ;5;0;0      
           ;6;1;3      
L15698A2;              
           ;4;2;4      
           ;5;0;0      
           ;6;0;0      
L2281A2;               
           ;4;1;2      
           ;5;0;0      
12302C;                
           ;1;8;11     
           ;2;1;1      
           ;3;1;1      
           ;4;1;2      
           ;5;2;4      
           ;6;0;0
```

I want the output to be

```
L12194C;1;8 ;12        
L12194C;2;30;46        
L12194C;3;49;71        
L12194C;4;0;0          
L12194C;5;0;0          
L12194C;6;1;3          

L15698A2;4;2;4         
L15698A2;5;0;0         
L15698A2;6;0;0         

L2281A2;4;1;2          
L2281A2;5;0;0          

12302C;1;8;11          
12302C;2;1;1           
12302C;3;1;1           
12302C;4;1;2           
12302C;5;2;4           
12302C;6;0;0
```

Answer (score 1):

use `AWk` :

```
awk '!/^[[:blank:]]/{j=$1;print "";next}{print j$1}' FILENAME
```

output:

```
L12194C;;1;8;12
L12194C;;2;30;46
L12194C;;3;49;71
L12194C;;4;0;0
L12194C;;5;0;0
L12194C;;6;1;3

L15698A2;;4;2;4
L15698A2;;5;0;0
L15698A2;;6;0;0

L2281A2;;4;1;2
L2281A2;;5;0;0

12302C;;1;8;11
12302C;;2;1;1
12302C;;3;1;1
12302C;;4;1;2
12302C;;5;2;4
12302C;;6;0;0
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
sed -E '
    1{ h; d; }
    /^[^ \t]/{ h; s/.*//; p; d; }
    s/^[ \t]+;//; G; s/^(.*)\n(.*)$/\2\1/'
```

Output:

```
L12194C;1;8;12
L12194C;2;30;46
L12194C;3;49;71
L12194C;4;0;0
L12194C;5;0;0
L12194C;6;1;3

L15698A2;4;2;4
L15698A2;5;0;0
L15698A2;6;0;0

L2281A2;4;1;2
L2281A2;5;0;0

12302C;1;8;11
12302C;2;1;1
12302C;3;1;1
12302C;4;1;2
12302C;5;2;4
12302C;6;0;0
```

Answer (score 0):

Are the fields constant? Meaning, every field between the ;'s are related data... If the fields are constant, personally, I'd use a database such as sqlite and insert the data into the db and then use queries to output the data the way you need it. You can also use an array and then arrange the fields in the output that way too.

Comment: yes they are. I only need unix commands to duplicate the field in the first column

Comment: The data format above is not the data format I responded to (must have been edited after I responded)... my solution will not work for your data format. Please disregard.

Answer (score 0):

Another `sed`:

```
sed -ne'h;s/.*//p;x;:n' -e'N;s/;.* //p;tn' -eD <in >out
```

`sed` saves a copy of pattern space to `h`old space, `s///`ubstitutes away all of pattern space and `p`rints the results, then e`x`changes `h`old and pattern spaces. This happens on each non-blank 1st field line, and gets the dividing blanks in output where appropriate.

For every other line `sed` also appends the `N`ext following an inserted `\n`ewline delimiter, then attempts to `s///`ubstitute away all of pattern space between the first semicolon and last space. If both of those chars occur in pattern space, the substitution `t`ests successful, and `sed` branches back to the `:n`ext label to try again.

Else `sed` `D`eletes up to and including the first occurring `\n`ewline in pattern space before starting over from the top w/ whatever remains.

My results:

```
L12194C;1;8;12
L12194C;2;30;46
L12194C;3;49;71
L12194C;4;0;0
L12194C;5;0;0
L12194C;6;1;3

L15698A2;4;2;4
L15698A2;5;0;0
L15698A2;6;0;0

L2281A2;4;1;2
L2281A2;5;0;0

12302C;1;8;11
12302C;2;1;1
12302C;3;1;1
12302C;4;1;2
12302C;5;2;4
```

Comment: sed -e:n -e'/./!n;$!N;/;.*\n *;/!D;s//;/p;tn' <in >out   this command work perfect. thank you so much

Comment: @Toufik - i guess i copy/pasted it wrong - i had blank line positions transposed. It should work now.

Comment: well it worked even in the previous command

Comment: @Toufik - ok! It's easier that way, i know. I rolled it back,